# my android app keeps stopping, and the logct is unclear to me, can somone help please?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I just cant understand the logcat becuse it does not state that the problem acured in my code but in the code that is automaticly generated by using firebase.

```
2021-06-02 21:55:21.444 11603-11603/com.example.sandwichswitch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sandwichswitch, PID: 11603
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
    at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2388)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2358)
    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6697)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1913)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: You should be targeting Java 8 in your build.gradle and not Java 7.